# Delphi TidSNMP Receive get messages port 161 how?

Tags: delphi, snmp, indy

I am trying to make my windows service respond to some MIB OID Get requests from other agents and then reply. Despite much searching I cant see how to do this. I cant see an obvious way to implement this with TidSNMP.

I have dabbled with TidUDPServer and listened to the raw socket but clearly there is a lot of structure to an SNMP message so I aborted that at this time.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks
Craig.

Answer (score 0):

The `TIdSNMP` component is an SNMP client. You need an SNMP server to receive messages.

You can get more information about what is available in Indy at http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html

Comment: Indy does not have an SNMP server component. You will have to use `TIdUDPServer` and implement the entire SNMP protocol manually.